# White space at the bottom of web page

Tags: css, http

Iv been editing this web template for the past few days but when a section is removed the page length stays the same. Everything seems fine with the css and I dont spot anything in the html. I am a beginner so outside eyes can hopefully get this white space taken care of. Check it out, any advice is appreciated: http://solidsm.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body tag has an inline style of  `height:5314px`.
I think that is causing the issue forcing the height to become more than the content height.
Why do you need that height constraint. Remove it .

Comment: Furthermore, it's being set with javascript.

Comment: @Gloria Thanks for the quick reply, can you specify exactly where this is being set at?

Comment: Right on the <body style="height: 5311px;">. Probably this height was setup during development process and it was forgotten to delete later. If this is not the case is been injected by javascript.

Comment: @Labanino I see that it is being injected by javascript. Thanks for the guidance ill try to handle it from here.